# python style: list of strings vs string.split()

Tags: python

In modules where a set of string literals is needed it can be declared as

```
values = ['hello', 'world']
```

But I have seen many experienced python programmers write

```
values = 'hello world'.split()
```

obviously considering it more readable. (I also think I have seen this in the python standard library source, but I'm not sure)

Does any python guide cite either of them as the preferred style, or does it come down to personal preference?

Answer (score 1):

In some instances, when you have longer strings, it's shorter and arguably more readable to use a `.split()` than to write out a list.

In your case, with a small string, it doesn't really matter; I would use just a list because `.split()` is longer. It really depends on your preference.

Answer (score 1):

`values = ['hello', 'world']` should be more efficient. Also **explicitly** shows that `values` is a list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

We can look at the source code.

#### [`split` source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/459cd61399f589caccae1c0fa2138ebcaaa63ea6/Objects/stringlib/split.h#L102)

It starts by initializing a new list:

```c
PyObject *list = PyList_New(PREALLOC_SIZE(maxcount));
```

Then doing the `separator` parameter lookup:

```c
    while ((j < str_len) && (maxcount-- > 0)) {
        for(; j < str_len; j++) {
            /* I found that using memchr makes no difference */
            if (str[j] == ch) {
                SPLIT_ADD(str, i, j);
                i = j = j + 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

`SPLIT_ADD` actually calls `PyList_SET_ITEM` which inserts a certain object to the memory array.

#### Conclusion

Even without actually checking time differences, I can only assume that this lookup will be slower (even if a bit) than strictly initializing a list.